# Retrieve and Abort open XMLHttpRequest objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Does the browser have some way to target open requests?

I have a plugin that calls some requests, which doesn't expose the XMLHttpRequest/jqXHR object; however, Firebug does show these requests' operations in the console.

Is there a way to reference the objects for open requests?  The end goal is to abort existing one.

Comment: I don't think so. You're likely better off looking for a way to hook into the plugin and making the xhr available that way. Or, if you know for a fact that it is using jQuery, you can monkeypatch the $.ajax method.

Comment: @KevinB You can also just listen for all `open` calls. Obviously it woul be preferable to hook into the plugin itself.

Comment: @KevinB: I don't know that for a fact, without delving into its code

Comment: @plalx: yeah, that might be what I need to do

Answer (score 1):

I believe that a FF extension has more capabilities than the code running in the page's context and that's why it can detect requests. As far as I know there's no native way to retrieve an XMLHttpRequest object instance if you haven't kept any reference to it.

However, JavaScript is a flexible language and you can easily create an interceptor that would track all open calls.

*Note: It would be preferable to hook in the plugin methods if possible.*

E.g.

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = (function (nativeSendFn) {
    return function () {
        var sendHandler = this.constructor.onSend;
        nativeSendFn.apply(this, arguments);

        sendHandler && sendHandler(this, arguments);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);

XMLHttpRequest.onSend = function (xhr, args) {
    console.log('request ', xhr);
    console.log('arguments ', args);
};

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.open('GET', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com', true);
req.send();
```

Comment: I'll have to look into this.  It seems like it should work.  Instead of `console.log(...)` I think I'd add the object to  `window.oXMLHttpRequests` so I can reference it later.  I'd also need to hook into the close to remove it from the object.

Comment: @vol7ron Yeah it's hard to give a full implementation when I do not know exactly what you what to achieve, but that should give you the kick-start you need ;) I hooked into the `send` function so that you can cancel the request right away without having to store an instance, which requires some cleanup process to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: I guess I could have given more details.  I'm using the dataTables plugin and toggling destroying/creating tables via a toggle.  I don't think the plugin exposes the XMLHttpRequest object, but I want to abort the call if a user quickly toggles to avoid race conditions when loading the data.

Comment: @vol7ron Have you managed to come up with something using the solution I described?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. No, I had to diverge my attention elsewhere, but plan on returning to this.  I know FF is at a lower layer and processes the requests, which is why it can display and operate on the handles in the console.  I guess I'm curious if a handle is exposed somewhere in the `window` or `document` object.  I can see this being good for performance and functionality, but possibly a nightmare when it comes to security.  Still, it would be nice for what I was doing.